# How to process requests on stdin socket?

Tags: sockets, http, web, server

I am using a web server called lighttpd and they have a command line option -1 to accept a request on the stdin socket. I am fairly new to sockets and such, and their documentation does not say much about the syntax or examples of this options. Would I be able to send a simple http request through this option? And how would I do this?

Comment: I tested that already and it throws an error stdin is not a socket. I am asking if through this option with using sockets, is it possible to send an http request.

Comment: Looking at the [pull request](https://github.com/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4/pull/43) that first introduced the `-i` and `-1` options, this oneshot mode was designed to allow lighttpd to be started by [xinetd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/xinetd), which I think creates its own sockets and uses them to redirect the stdin/stdout of the child processes it spawns. So, this oneshot mode probably won't work when used manually in a terminal, for instance.

Comment: But isnt that what i want to happen
xinetd spins a new process via socket and sends data through stdin 
How would i do this

Comment: Outside of xinetd, YOU would not be able to do this from a terminal, it has to be done in code only.  Call `socket()` or `accept()` to create a viable socket descriptor as needed, and then execute a lighttpd process in `-1` mode using that socket as its redirected stdin.

Comment: Yes, xinetd opens the socket for you and links it to stdin, but it is still a socket. So you can call socket ioctl() calls on it and they would still work. But unfortunately that means it's incompatible with a terminal. You can tools like `wget` to test your webservice.